# I cannot find the proper Mac theme for my Ubuntu system. Help?

Tags: 15.10, themes

I've been trying for awhile now to get Macbuntu to work on my machine but it's incompatible and I cannot find any other versions.

I tried this **:** https://sourceforge.net/projects/macbuntu/

And I have tried this **:** http://www.noobslab.com/2015/11/macbuntu-1510-transformation-pack-for.html

The first one will download but isn't compatible and the second I can't even find a download for it even though it's apparently on that page.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 right now.

Comment: You don't have to download anything from the second link (at least not manually) - just follow the instructions on the page and execute the commands in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The [Themes Collection by NoobsLab](https://launchpad.net/%7Enoobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes?field.series_filter=utopic) PPA, which is up-to-date up to Ubuntu 18.04, has an interesting selection of themes for Ubuntu, including MBuntu. To add this PPA to your software sources, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install any of five different macbuntu packages for Ubuntu 15.10 and many other theme packages for Ubuntu 15.10 from the Ubuntu Software Center.

**Features**

- Themes are shiny, smooth, fast, and look like the latest Mac
- Mac Boot Splash auto configuration
- Mac theme for LightDM-webkit auto configuration
- Separate GTK themes for each desktop (Unity, Gnome Classic, Linux Mint)
- Latest icon set
- Three Docky themes
- Auto set themes and icons script

Comment: Oh. Linux is very confusing to me. I'm very much used to Windows.

Comment: My advice in this situation is to start with a computer that doesn't have any known hardware problems, so that your new operating system will be easier to understand. I learned this the hard way by starting off installing Linux on an old piece of junk, and it was not until I installed it alongside Windows on a new laptop that I saw Ubuntu for what it is.